# About Network Information System ( NIS ) - different releases of Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, administration

I want to set up an NIS server between two machines, that have different releases of Ubuntu (one is 14.04 and the another is 16.04). The problem is that because they have different releases, they have some system service accounts, which are different among them, like:

1. `saned` user has its home directory under `/home/saned` in the 14.04, but it has it under `/var/lib/saned` in the 16.04 version
2. `libuuid` user exists only in the 14.04 machine.

What I should do to properly configure the sharing of the `passwd` file between those machines?  Can I ignore those kinds of differences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I recognized,  NIS server just considers the user accounts. So there is no need to care about the confliction in the system accounts between the machines.